# Getting some data from HTML using regex

Tags: java, html, regex, string

I was trying to get some data from html. This is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String str = "<div class=\"b-vacancy-list-salary\">\n" +
                "            from 50 000\n" +
                "             to 70 000\n" +
                "             USD.\n" +
                "        </div>";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTagValues(str).toArray()));
    }


    static final String tag = "<div class=\"b-vacancy-list-salary\">\n";
    private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile(tag+"(.+?)</div>");

    private static List<String> getTagValues(final String str) {
        System.out.println(tag);
        final List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            tagValues.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return tagValues;
    }
```

It returns `[]`, but not value. What's wrong?

Comment: It's a usually a bad idea to parse html with regex - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: which values you want to get from the html ?

Comment: `from 50 000 to 70 000 USD`

Comment: @user2062950 by usually I assume you mean always for any reason.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus pretty much, unless you have a small amount of HTML with well known structure (that isn't going to change, which is rarely the case). the question I linked has some good discussion on the subject

Comment: @user2062950 Heh, yea, linked to the same question. I would still argue that using a low upkeep xml parser like lxml is still the right choice though.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `line feed`.

The better way to parse HTML is to use DOM parser or Xpath.

E.g :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      final String str = "<div class=\"b-vacancy-list-salary\">\n"
              + "            from 50 000\n"
              + "             to 70 000\n"
              + "             USD.\n"
              + "        </div>";
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTagValues(str).toArray()));
    }
    static final String tag = "<div class=\"b-vacancy-list-salary\">";
    private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile(tag + "(.+?)</div>");

    private static List<String> getTagValues(final String str) {
      System.out.println(tag);
      final List<String> tagValues = new ArrayList<String>();
      final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(str.replace("\n", ""));
      while (matcher.find()) {
        tagValues.add(matcher.group(1).trim());
      }
      return tagValues;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile(tag+"(.+?)</div>");
```

use

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile(tag+"([\\s|\\S]+?)</div>");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Tony Because HTML isn't a regular grammar; it's more complicated than one, and even an extended regular-expression matcher can't handle its structure. You need a recursive-descent parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Pattern.DOTALL` as the second parameter of `Pattern.compile`.  This enables the dot in the pattern to match newlines.  Not sure if this quite gives you what you want, but it may help you get started.

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile(tag + "(.+?)</div>",
                                                         Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Javadoc on DOTALL is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is not include the new line. try this:

```
Pattern.compile(tag + "((.|\n)*)</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the "." match newline characters, you can do this by putting "(?s)" at the front of your regular expression; so in your case, do Pattern.compile("(?s)" + tag + "(.+?)");